# EPPlus Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream

Tags: c#, nuget, epplus

I am using the EPPlus v5.7.5 library in my C# project.
When I use my code which generates an excel file, the code works during Visual Studio debugging.
After installing the same application via MSI setup (created in VS 2019), I can't create the excel file because I get the follwing error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.RecyclableMemory.GetStream()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ConstructNewFile(String password)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(FileInfo newFile)
   at Utilities.General.Files.Excel.EPPlusHandler.GenerateExcelFile(DataTable dataTable, ExtendedFileDetails fileDetails, Dictionary`2 alignment, Boolean isDotNetFramework, Action`1 exceptionHandler)
```

I am using Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=2.1.3.0 because on the EPPlus library documentation they mentioned that we can use v>= v1.4

** The code is located on a common project. If I use it from another project, it request the RecyclableMemoryStream v2.1.2.

What should I do to fix it? I want to use the latest version of both nugets. Currently I an using in each project a different version of the nuget to overcome this...

Comment: Are you using .net framework or .net core?

Comment: @JHBonarius .net framework. I posted an answer

Answer (score 5):

Try re-installing `Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream` from Nuget. That helped me once I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this Problem. In my case the issue was the missing config file of the executable ({xyz}.exe.config).
The File basicly lets the Application bind to an alternative Version of the library in question:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.1.0" newVersion="2.2.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I solved it downgrading the Nuget version of `Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream` to version 1.4.1.

I had version 2.2.0 installed and `dependentAssembly/bindingRedirect` wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I added Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream to both the Main project(API) and the Service project that ExcelPackage is called in.
The problem was solved.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream dll missing in the location. just place Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream dll